# Visual Glitch whenever loading emacs

Tags: buffers, microsoft-windows, frames, files

I am running emacs on WSL, and whenever I load emacs I get the following screen: [image]

It goes away for a half second whenever I click on it, but then it comes back. Very new to this so am unsure what is going on. How does one fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with WSL2 under Windows 11 on a Surface Pro 7.  I tried several things, none of which helped, and then I updated my video driver and it's been rock solid ever since.

Throughout Microsoft's WSL/WSLg web pages they do mention that it's **very important** for WSLg/Wayland to work that you update your video driver to the latest from the manufacturer. But **then** both Microsoft (laptop vendor) and Intel (driver vendor) warn that if you update from Intel (the driver vendor) then you risk losing any special customizations/configurations that the OEM vendor (Microsoft in this case) may have made and worst case you could even lose your video entirely. They both recommend going to the laptop vendor site and upgrading from there as the safe path - so that's what I had (previously) done. But in the case of the Surface Pro Microsoft does offer a single package that installs/reinstalls all the Surface drivers and firmware and puts everything back to "original" so I applied that (early on) but no joy. So armed with that as a "backup" I went ahead and upgraded from the Intel (driver vendor) site at [www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html) being careful to select the right video hardware and "generation", etc. The vendor driver update went smoothly (I may have passed out holding my breath once or twice during the process, it took a while) but then after a reboot I brought up emacs and it seems rock solid. No video weirdness whatsoever, new frames are fine, splitting windows is flawless, everything is exactly as I've known emacs to be for, well, a long time.

Since I'm on a Microsoft Surface Pro 7, my laptop vendor (Microsoft) updates their video driver offering "periodically" and of course my video vendor (Intel) offers updates on their (different) schedule.  And since a Surface Pro 7 is getting a little old Microsoft was a good bit behind Intel's update schedule.

While ignoring that "warning" can be risky, I can say that my Surface Pro 7 is running perfectly with no Windows or other issues as a result of the upgrade.  And my entire WSL/WSLg environment is rock solid and really nice. But of course I might just be lucky.  :)